# How to display an image from blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to understand the documentation [Using the Images Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html) and I am confused about how to get the key and display the avatar.

Documentation says that the `Image` handler will serve the image off the `/img` path.

I am confused about what this `Image` handler does. I comment below how understand it; please correct. Thanks:

```
class Image (webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #get the key of the image "img_id" from datastore
        #what is the value of "img_id"? Where does it come from?
        #how does the app engine know to get what key for which image?
        greeting = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
        #what is greeting.avatar?
        #is it img_id.avatar ?
        #I assume "avatar" refers to the "avatar" property in the model
        if greeting.avatar:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            #does this display the avatar?
            #I thought the img tag displayed the avatar
            self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
       else:
          self.error(404)
```

Many thanks for your help.

---

**UPDATE** (re: answer by Gabi Purcaru)

Thanks again for the clear answer. I have a query that displays the user comments like this:

```
    for result in results:
        self.response.out.write("<li>")
        self.response.out.write("<b>%s</b> %s " % (result.userName, result.userLatestComment))
        self.response.out.write("</li>")
    self.response.out.write("</ol></body></html>")
```

so, I copy the line with the image tag from the [MainPage handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html#Serving)

```
self.response.out.write("<div><img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" % greeting.key())
```

and change

```
greeting.key()
```

to

```
result.key()
```

I assume that, this should now display the avatar next to the user comment:

```
    for result in results:
        self.response.out.write("<li>")
        self.response.out.write("<b>%s</b> %s " % (result.userName, result.userLatestComment))
        self.response.out.write("<div><img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" % result.key())
        self.response.out.write("</li>")
    self.response.out.write("</ol></body></html>")
```

but still not clear why `result.key()` is the key of the image I want to display?

Comment: The value of img_id is the datastore key that specifies the precise location of the specific Image object in datastore.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html  Performing a get using this key will retrieve the greeting if it exists.

Comment: @kevpie: thanks. How does the app engine know which `img_id` to get in this line `greeting = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))`?

Comment: This is not blobstore. This is a blob in the datastore. You need to read the docs about Blobstore really carefully. You confuse the two concepts I am afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `"img_id"` comes from the GET part of the url (something like "www.example.com/img?**img_id=12312**"). The engine assigns a new unique key for every model in the database.
2. `greeting.avatar` is the avatar property of the model with the key `img_id`. So, in some sense, you can think of it like `img_id.avatar`, although technically it is not correct.
3. that does not display the avatar, it is just returning the avatar. Let's take a usual image for example for you to understand better. When you write `<img src="some_link" />`, the browser will look for `"some_link"`, and include that image. The browser will then read the image from the filesystem, and return it to the browser. What your handler does is changing the backend part, so that the webserver will return the image from the datastore (specifically that `avatar` property) instead of a regular file. The browser -- and the user -- will see it as a regular image.

**EDIT:**
`result.key()` is the unique identifier that the database automatically gave your model. You need to "tell it" to the image handler you just wrote, for it to know which particular model avatar you need. You do that by setting the `img_id` GET variable for the url (which you just did).

I am not sure if you understand the whole `.key()` thing. Let me explain that:

Any database needs to identify one record from another (model in our case). This is why they will *automatically* assign a new, and most importantly **unique** identifier (key in our case) to each and every record inserted in the database. You will have to provide the model's key for your handler to return the avatar of that model.

Let's take a real-world example: you are an individual amongst many. The way that your country uniquely identifies you is by some kind of SSN (Social Security Number). In my country it is a 13-digits code (e.g. `1024582485008`). If I want to get my driver licence, I will have to provide my name, but that is not enough -- I'm not the only Gabi Purcaru in my country. I will also have to provide my SSN, which will tell exactly *who* I am. If we make an analogy, you have to provide the model's "SSN" (i.e. key) to the handler, so that it will know *which* model to get from the database and return it's avatar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This clarifies a lot; but I am still not clear how `db.get(self.request.get("img_id")` gets the `img_id` for the avatar we want to get. I don't see any instruction here saying "get the `img_id` associated with an avatar associated with a certain user." Thanks again.

Comment: I added an update. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel, results is from a query for the entities in datastore.  They key for each entity is emited as an img src url in the html.  When the browser tries to load that img src, it hits the Image handler with the key.  The key is used in the db.get and then the bytes from the blob property are returned following the contentType header.  Is this helping?

Comment: @kevpie: But what I don't understand is that the entity returned by the query result is not the image; or `result.avatar`. But in any case; the handler `AvatarSave` is not writing the image to the blobstore. Do you have any suggestions why? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel, this is not using blobstore.  This is one of the ambiguous things in datastore.  A blob property is not a blobstore object.  This example only uses a plain blob property.  You will need to refer to the blobstore examples and further to the things like the get_serving_url if you want to leverage the picasa image serving infrastructure or store large binary objects.  Blobstore is not a datastore BlobProperty.

Comment: @kevpie: I was about to comment the same thing. Where can I find info on how to display image stored in Blobstore?

Comment: @John https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions you can create a serving url by passing the blobkey to get_serving_url().  This url will then serve your image. You can create urls for BlobStore images and CloudStorage images. These urls are served up over a separate infrastructure than your AppEngine instances.